# How to continue last session, after network disconnect?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erlangweb, erlang-driver

I am working in android application using ejabberd as a server.I make call to user using VOIP. I disconnected from server when my internet connection goes down.After internet connection come, I need to continue last session,before timeout occurs.I found XMPP extension XEP-0198 stream management , but This extension is not implemented in ejabberd.And this extension implemented in prosody server and some clients.But what I want is should not re-login, this means opening a new stream , TLS ,SASL authentication and resource binding should not occurs while continue previous session, and directly resume previous session.Is there any other alternative for this?

Comment: Hi, there is a commercial offering from process-one that allows re-attachs and other features useful for mobile clients.  Check the "Mobile" section on this comparison page https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/protocols/   (disclamer: I work for p1)